# Allow moderators to merge an answer with the question, under some circumstances

Tags: feature-request, questions, answers, moderator-tools

Maybe this is only a problem with small sites. What I notice on *Drupal Answers*, where users are not required to register an account to ask questions, is that sometimes a user asks a question with an account, somebody writes a comment for that question, and the user tries to edit the question with a different account; when the user notices he cannot edit the question, he instead writes an answer.

> [image: screenshot]

In the past, moderators could merge two accounts, but now they cannot. To tell the truth, merging the accounts just to be able to merge the answer with the question is probably a bit too much. In fact, it *could* be perfectly fine to have an account for the questions asked because of work, and one account for personal questions; as long as the accounts are not used to vote each other, or vote for users twice, there should not be any reason to merge the accounts.

As it is currently implemented, an answer can be merged with the question (that is, put the answer's text in the question, and delete the answer), when both the answer and the question have been written using the same account.
Considering users can use unregistered accounts, which exist uniquely in a single browser, and when the user doesn't clean cookies, I would request to make possible for the moderators to merge the answer with the question even if the accounts used for the posts are different.

Considering that it is always possible to reverse the operation done, since the answer is simply soft-deleted (and moderators and 10k+ users see the deleted post), and the appended text is added as new revision (and revisions can be reverted by moderators), I don't see any harm in allowing the moderators to always be able to merge an answer into a question, even when the involved accounts are different.

If that is excessive, I am fine also with allowing the operation only when some criteria are met. For example, the operation could be allowed if the gravatar is the same in both cases, or the IP used to access both the accounts is the same. I am perfectly fine also with a warning that alerts the moderators when the operation is done and the accounts are not the same; this would at least avoid inadvertently doing something by mistake.

Comment: Edit question, copy/paste, delete answer?

Comment: That could be done also when the answer is written by the user who asked the question. There should not need to do that with a mouse click, but since there is such possibility, it should be used when needed. I don't have statistics, but I feel it happens more times that the people who writes an edit for the question as answer are the ones that use two unregistered accounts, or an unregistered account and a registered one. Why? Because those people usually ask questions; they don't try to comment on others' questions.